# Could have filled

Tags: modal-verbs

> All students could have filled the application.

Could this statement mean that every student were eligible for filling ?( we didn't want to mean that they didn't fill the application) , I want to use it as an information not with the meaning that "It’s possible that every student has filled in the application "

Comment: It certainly does not mean that every student *did* fill out the application. For that, just use *all students **filled** (out) the application.* What is it that you're trying to express by not saying it directly?

Comment: Could it mean that every student were eligible for filling?

Comment: For example we want to inform someone that every student were eligible to fill the application ( but the choice to fill or not fill the application up to them, and we didn't know who fill the application who didn't)

Comment: Sure, but you could then say *All students **were eligible** to fill out the application.*

Comment: Could we  say "All I know that all students could have filled the application , but I didn't know if all of them did "

Comment: *All I know **is** that all students could have filled (out) the application, but I **don't** know if all of them did.* The tenses aside, you keep saying *filled the application*, but you really need to say *filled **out** the application*.

Comment: Maybe you meant "All students may have filled the application" or did you mean "It's possible that all student filled the application". Maybe even "Every student had the right to fill the application"?